# MySQL: Creating a new table with information from a query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

In MySQL, I would like to create a new table with all the information in this query:

```
select * into consultaa2 from SELECT
 CONCAT(    'UPDATE customers SET
 customers_default_address_id= ',    
 (SELECT a.address_book_id FROM
 address_book a where
 c.customers_id=a.customers_id order by
 address_book_id desc limit 1),    '
 WHERE customers_id = ', customers_id,
 ';') AS sql_statement FROM customers c
 where c.customers_id > 3894;
```

The query is too long for the browser to show the concat and I need this to make this updates.

Comment: Answer by Daniel Hilgarth is the "correct" answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Note that **this method does not *create* a table** (as per OP title). To do that see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595301/8112776).*

---

Inserting into a table with information from a query is of the format

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE-1> 
SELECT * FROM <TABLE-2>
```

In your case, it would be

```
insert into consultaa2 
SELECT CONCAT( 'UPDATE customers SET customers_default_address_id= ',
(SELECT a.address_book_id FROM address_book a where c.customers_id=a.customers_id order by address_book_id desc limit 1), ' WHERE customers_id = ', customers_id, ';') AS sql_statement FROM customers c where c.customers_id > 3894;
```

Just make sure the columns in the table you are inserting into and the columns returned from the select query match.

Comment: You know I tried the same and didn't work, I just realized that because it was a query the mysql didn't know what type of field to create, really crazy but fixed by creating manually table and field :)

Comment: The @daniel-hilgarth answer is actually the right one to Saikios question since it will create the new table based on the selected table sctructure. Saikios query syntax looks a lot like TSQL syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 161):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename SELECT * FROM othertable;
```

`tablename` is the name of the new table you want to create, `SELECT * FROM othertable` is the query that returns the data the table should be created from.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this, but only create a temporary table?

Comment: @kevando yes, it is:`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tablename AS (SELECT * FROM othertable);`

Comment: And is it possible to do it just like this but adding an extra field not in the original query? For example, I'd like to add a primary key for the table like `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. How can this be done?

Comment: You can create a view which is like a temporary table. It will update as your othertable updates. CREATE VIEW tablename as SELECT * FROM othertable;

Answer (score 14):

**mysql create new table**

Example from mysql commandline.

```
mysql> create table foo(id int, vorta text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

**Insert rows**

```
mysql> insert into foo values(1, 'for the hoarde');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

**look what's in there**

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+----------------+
| id   | vorta          |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | for the horde  |
+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Create a new table with information from a query**

```
mysql> create table foo2 select * from foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Check if the data moved**

```
mysql> select * from foo2;
+------+----------------+
| id   | vorta          |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | for the horde  |
+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```